# Android Json Parsing with Gson

Tags: android, gson, json

I am tring to map json data using Gson from a URL to my java class. This is the code for the class:

```
public class Sessions {
public Boolean active;
public String contributor_covu_id;
public String created_at;
public String key;
public String status;

public Boolean getActive() {
    return active;
}
public void setActive(Boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}
public String getContributor_covu_id() {
    return contributor_covu_id;
}
public void setContributor_covu_id(String contributor_covu_id) {
    this.contributor_covu_id = contributor_covu_id;
}
public String getCreated_at() {
    return created_at;
}
public void setCreated_at(String created_at) {
    this.created_at = created_at;
}
public String getKey() {
    return key;
}
public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
public String type;
```

}

and this is the code of the class that calls the service and maps json

```
public static List<Sessions> getSessions(String urlString)
        throws IOException {

    Sessions[] sessions;
    List<Sessions> tempList = null;
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonb.create();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    // Response response = null;
    JSONObject j = null;

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
    }

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    conn.disconnect();

    try {
        j = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        sessions = gson.fromJson(j.toString(), Sessions[].class);
        tempList = Arrays.asList(sessions);

        // response = gson.fromJson(j.toString(), Response.class);
        // tempList.add(response);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tempList;
}
```

Although the code is correct, I get a Gson exception "Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class com.test.Sessions;. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem"

How do i solve this issue and return the Gson as an ArrayList?

Comment: Just as a side-comment, code that reads JSON has at least one bug (does not specify input encoding), and is pretty inefficient due to reading content line-by-line (should just pass input source straight to JSON parsing library). And finally, there is on need to create intermediate JSONObject, instead of directly data binding content (which GSON can do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

```
public class Sessions {

private String status;
private List<Session> sessions;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public List<Session> getSessions() {
    return sessions;
}

public void setSessions(List<Session> sessions) {
    this.sessions = sessions;
}

public static class Session {
    public Boolean active;
    public String contributor_covu_id;
    public String created_at;
    public String key;
    public String status;
    public String name;

};
```

}

Comment: Create a Main Class with a nested class and return that as an object to the Gson mapper.

Answer (score 2):

Add a constructor to your `Sessions` class:

```
public class Sessions {
    public Boolean active;
    public String contributor_covu_id;
    public String created_at;
    public String key;
    public String status;

    void Sessions()
    {
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: i am getting the same error. Is my code to call the service correct?

Comment: There was a typo in my original code: The method name was `Session` and not `Sessions`. Please try it again.

Comment: i am still getting this exception Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class com.test.sessions;. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.

Comment: a constructor is supposed to be Sessions() and not Session()

Comment: That isn't a constructor... you need `public Sessions()` not `void Sesssions()`

Comment: none of this works, i have tried all possible solutions, even subclassing to a static class. This gson issue has waster 4 hours of my time.

Comment: I have solved it myself, the issue was that we had to create a list of nested classes